# Integrating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x \frac{x^{2 k +1}}{\cosh \left( x- y\right)} $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function

> For $y>0$, I'm trying to compute in a closed form the following integral: $$ I =\int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{x^{2 k +1}}{\cosh \left( x- y\right)} \mathrm{d} x$$

---

Here is my attempt to a solution:

$$I  =   I_1 + I_2 = \int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x \frac{x^{2 k +1}}{\cosh \left( x- y\right)} + \int_{y}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x \frac{x^{2 k +1}}{\cosh \left( x- y\right)} $$

I believe that you can compute $I_2$ by expanding the denominator as follows:

\begin{align}I_2&= 2\int_{y}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x \frac{x^{2 k +1}}{e^{\left( x- y\right)} + e^{-\left( x- y\right)}} \\&= 2\int_{y}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x  e^{-\left( x- y\right)} \frac{x^{2 k +1}}{1 + e^{- 2\left( x- y\right)}} \\&= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}z  e^{-z}  \frac{(y + z)^{2 k +1}}{1 + e^{-2 z}} \\&= 2 \sum_{n=0}^{2 k + 1} \binom{2k +1}{ n} y^{2k + 1- n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}z  e^{-z}  \frac{z^n}{1 + e^{-2 z}}\end{align}

Now we recall the definition of the Lerch Transcendent:
$$\Phi(z, s, a) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^m}{(z + a)^s}$$

And we obtain:

\begin{align}I_2 &=  2 \sum_{n=0}^{2 k + 1} \binom{2k +1}{ n} y^{2k + 1- n} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}z  e^{-(1 + 2m)z} z^n \\&= 2 \sum_{n=0}^{2 k + 1} \binom{2k +1}{ n} \Gamma (n + 1) 2^{1+ n} y^{2k + 1- n} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{(n + 1/2)^{n +1}} \\&= 2 \sum_{n=0}^{2 k + 1} \binom{2k+1}{ n} \Gamma (n + 1) 2^{1+ n} y^{2k + 1- n} \Phi(-1, n+ 1, 1/2)\end{align}

Therefore the second piece evaluates to a polynomial in $y$.
My main issue is about $I_1$: I can not understand what is the best strategy to tackle the integration, since a similar treatment to $I_2$ does not seem to be available. I will be very grateful to anyone helping on this problem.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2k+1}}{\cosh(x-y)}\,\mathrm{d}x=(2k+1)!\cdot 2\operatorname{Ti}_{2k+2}(e^y)$ is probably(?) the most succinct way to state the result, where $\operatorname{Ti}_s$ is the [inverse tangent integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_tangent_integral).

Comment: @user10354138 How did you find your answer? Could you provide any more detail?

Comment: Establish this formula for $y<0$ (so $e^y<1$ is inside the domain for the series definition of $\operatorname{Ti}_s$) by expanding the geometric series similar to how you do $I_2$.  Note the integral $I=I(y)$ is analytic on horizontal strip $\lvert\Im(y)\rvert<\frac\pi2$, so uniqueness of analytic continuation gives result as we analytic continue inside this strip to $y>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, let's focus on $I_1$:

$$ I_1 = \int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x \frac{x^{2 k +1}}{\cosh \left( x- y\right)} $$

Given the nature of $\cosh x$, we can rewrite the integral as:

$$I_1 = \int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x \frac{x^{2 k +1}}{\frac{e^{x-y} + e^{-x+y}}{2}}$$

Simplifying further:

$$I_1 = 2 \int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x x^{2 k +1} \frac{1}{e^{x-y} + e^{-x+y}}$$

Now, make a substitution to transform the integral in a way that's easier to deal with:

Let's use $z = x - y$, which implies $x = z + y$.

When $x = 0 $, $z = -y $ and when $x = y$, $z = 0 $. So the new limits of integration are $[-y, 0]$.

This gives:

$$ dx = dz $$
$$x^{2 k +1} = (z + y)^{2 k +1}$$

Plug these in to get:

$$I_1 = 2 \int_{-y}^{0} \mathrm{d}z (z + y)^{2 k +1} \frac{1}{e^z + e^{-z}} $$

This form should be easier to work with, though it's still a challenge due to the nature of the exponential functions in the denominator.

To proceed, consider the series expansion:

$$\frac{1}{e^z + e^{-z}} = \frac{e^{-z}}{1 + e^{-2z}}$$

You can expand $ \frac{e^{-z}}{1 + e^{-2z}} $ in a power series around $ e^{-2z} $:

$$ \frac{e^{-z}}{1 + e^{-2z}} = e^{-z} (1 - e^{-2z} + e^{-4z} - e^{-6z} + \dots) $$

Now, integrating term by term:

$$ \int \mathrm{d}z (z + y)^{2 k +1} e^{-z} e^{-2nz} $$

For each term, you'll have:

$$ \int_{-y}^{0} \mathrm{d}z (z + y)^{2 k +1} e^{-(1+2n)z} $$

This integral will yield polynomials of $y$ when expanded, albeit the calculations may become intensive for large $ k $.

However, an analytical closed-form solution for the integral as a function of $ y $ and $ k $ without the series expansion may not be readily obtainable due to its complexity.

Comment: Please actually use MathJax the correct way with `$ ... $` and `$$ ... $$` on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Starting form @Arham Mehta's answer
$$\int_{-y}^{0} (z + y)^{2 k +1} e^{-(1+2n)z}\,\mathrm{d}z =$$ $$\frac{e^{(2 n+1) y}}{(2 n+1)^{2( k+1)} }\Big(\Gamma (2 (k+1))-\Gamma (2( k+1),(2 n+1) y)\Big)$$

Comment: Great! Do you see a way to also sum the remaining series in $n$?

Comment: @Physicistindisguise. Certainly.... not!